# How to join multiple tables using JPA JPQL?

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

I want to join three tables in a query but I do not know how to do that.

I tried:

```
List<Subclasses> list=em.createNativeQuery("select a.*,b.*,c.* from Subclasses a,Subs b,Klasses c where Subclasses.subid=Subs.subid and Subclasses.Klassid=Klasses.klassid");
```

But, I did not work.

Comment: Joins in JPQL are based on associations (ManyToOne, OneToMany, etc.) between entities. The JPA spec, the Hibernate documentation, and probably lots of JPA tutorials cover that.

Comment: I don't think that `createNativeQuery()` is  a suitable method for `JPQL`.

Comment: Please,I don't know how to use these associations. can you please use it in a query from my own query i used? please

Comment: Read a TUTORIAL. Read documentation. Here's one http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql.html  There are MANY MANY others, and other people here have advised already. Saying "i'm new to this" is simply not an excuse. If you go off and read a tutorial/doc and then have a query about a particular example on that page then you post a question about that particular case and what exactly you don't understand

Comment: I have checked several docs but just don't understand ... please,I just need a working code

Comment: Like what do I do in the two entity classes I want to join?

Comment: What do I do in the session bean class and jsp pages?

Comment: I read something online and got confused:can someone help please?

Comment: select p.title,p.stamp.author,pp.body from Post p join p.postpart pp           ...What I don't understand is the p.stamp.author and the p.postpart when the entities are Post and Post_part ... how comes about the p.postpart without the underscore and the stamp in p.stamp.author ?  column names of Post are :post_id,title,author,email,post_date,post_part_id    and for the Post_part :post_part_id,body,post_id